# ¿Qué tengo que hacer después de un git pull?

Tags: git, pull

**El problema ocurre en esta secuencia:**

1. `git checkout develop`
2. `git checkout -b nueva-rama`
3. Trabajo en el nuevo cambio
4. Alguien hace un `pull request` & `merge a develop`
5. `git checkout develop`
6. `git pull`
7. Aquí mi problema es si debo hacer un merge de develop a nueva-rama ,o crear una nueva rama que se base en develop y ahí agregarle los cambios que hice en nueva-rama, o como es que yo debería integrar mis cambios al ultimo pull request.
8. También tengo duda si esta seria la manera mas idónea de trabajar por que si alguien sube otro pull request me imagino que va a ser mas complicado.
9. En si no puedo hacer un push & pull request de una rama a develop por que trabajamos sobre los mismos archivos así que si hago pull request estaría sobrescribiendo los cambios del ultimo pull request.

**Describe lo que has intentado**
pues por el momento no he intentado nada, porque no quiero arruinar el trabajo.

Comment: Aunque trabajen en los mismos archivos pueden hacer pull porque git te hace visualizar si hay conflictos entre las diferentes líneas editadas. Sabiendo esto podrían organizarse y dividirse las funciones en las que trabajan al interno de un mismo archivo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por experiencia, es posible que en el futuro te vuelva a pasar que hagan nuevamente un PR (pull request) y lo mergeen a develop antes de que siquiera tu puedas terminar tus cambios, suele suceder mucho en los equipos de trabajo donde hay varios desarrolladores. Ambas opciones son viables, tanto borrar la rama actual para crear otra nueva con los cambios nuevos de develop, como la opción de mergear lo de develop a tu rama actual sin borrar nada.

Si tus cambios en tu nueva rama son pequeños o fáciles de volver a implementar, te recomiendo que borres esa rama y crees una nueva desde los cambios más recientes de develop. Esta opción es recomendable si tienes la sensación de "no querer arruinar el trabajo", es la más segura, pues estás haciendo un pull limpio sin mezclar nada con tu código de tu rama.

Si por otra parte, tienes la confianza de manejarte con git, la cual recomiendo yo como developer es que en vez de borrar la rama y perder tus cambios, en vez de hacer `git commit` y luego hacer merge desde develop (que podría generar conflictos y el temor de dejar la embarrada), es hacer un stash de tus cambios. **Git Stash** es para "dejar guardados" tus cambios sin realmente commitearlos ni pushearlos, pero quedan ahí como "en el aire". Entonces, una vez haces `git stash`, luego haces el `git merge` de develop a tu rama actual (tu rama actual estará tal cual la creaste la primera vez, antes de tus cambios), y te quedas con los cambios de develop en tu rama (no debiera haber conflictos al ser un merge, y si los hay, obviamente quédate con los cambios de develop que son los más recientes). Luego traes tus cambios desde stash con `git stash pop` y listo.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda lo que te he contado desde mi experiencia sintiendo el mismo temor con el sistema de control de versiones :)

Answer (score 0):

La forma en la que yo trabajo es haciendo rebases sobre la rama base (o `pull -r`). Eso permite mantener el desarrollo de un feature como una sola línea recta sin merges y eso permite hacer operaciones más enrevesadas con cierta facilidad (por ejemplo, un backport.... si hay merges de por medio en el desarrollo de un feature, hacer un backport se vuelve algo más complicado que hacer un simple rebase del feature).

Otra forma de obtener los cambios de la rama base es haciendo merge y luego un squash para que quede todo como un solo commit.... por ejemplo, esto es lo que yo hago en esos casos:

```
git pull # me traigo los ultimos cambios de la rama base
git reset --soft rama-base # coloco el "apuntador" de mi rama sobre la punta de la rama base
# en este punto, todas las diferencias entre la rama base y mi rama
# (o sea, todos los cambios de mi feature, ni mas ni menos) estan en el index listos para ser acometidos
git commit "mi feature" # en este punto mi feature se convierte en un único commit
# en este momento podría hacer el push (forzado, sin dudas) para que se vea reflejado en el MR/PR
```